# Places API not running OnSuccessListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-places-api, google-places

I've been working on a program an Android app for X Android phone that finds Places based on their Place ID, but for some reason it seems that the onSuccessListener isn't being ran. I've put a check in place to find out when the request is complete, but when it is reached the request has not been completed. All imports are working, the request and client both have values, but the requests are not returning anything. If anyone can help it'd be much appreciated.

Method that fetches the Place from the API:

```
private void initializePlace() {
    List<Place.Field> placeFields =Arrays.asList(Place.Field.LAT_LNG, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.PHONE_NUMBER, Place.Field.OPENING_HOURS);
    FetchPlaceRequest pRequest = FetchPlaceRequest.newInstance(placeId, placeFields);

    PlacesClient placesClient = MainActivity.getPlacesClient();

    Task<FetchPlaceResponse> placeTask = placesClient.fetchPlace(pRequest);
    placeTask.addOnSuccessListener(response -> {
        setPlace(response.getPlace());
        Log.i(TAG, "Place found" + place.getName());
    });

    placeTask.addOnFailureListener(exception -> {
        if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
            int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
            // Handle error with given status code.
            Log.e(TAG, "Place not found: " + exception.getMessage());
        }
    });

    placeTask.addOnCompleteListener(response -> Log.e(TAG, "done"));

    if(placeTask.isComplete()) {
        openHours = place.getOpeningHours();
        address = place.getAddress();
        latLng = place.getLatLng();
        phoneNumber = place.getPhoneNumber();
    }
}
```

````
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: co.binarylife.findyourfairleigh, PID: 1296
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.binarylife.findyourfairleigh/co.binarylife.findyourfairleigh.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.getName()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place.getName()' on a null object reference
        at co.binarylife.findyourfairleigh.FairleighBusiness.getName(FairleighBusiness.java:108)
        at co.binarylife.findyourfairleigh.MainActivity.initializeListView(MainActivity.java:123)
        at co.binarylife.findyourfairleigh.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:48)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858) ```
````

Comment: Have you tried logging the entire response with both an `onSuccessListener()` and an `onFailureListener()`? Does anything show up in the logs?

Comment: Where have you initialized `place`? Please post your full code so that we can help from our side.

Comment: @TaslimOseni neither the onSuccessListner, onFailureListener nor the onCompleteListner are ran at all. None of the code in the listeners are executed. Kinda feels like the request might have timed out or something, since there's just no response at all.

Comment: @evan the client's initialized, the token, request, client and task all have valid values during runtime at this point in the program. The place ids are also all hardcoded so there's really no reason it shouldn't be working, but, whatever the problem should be in this method, I believe. I'll add the rest of the code for the Places API client, but most of the code that handles the api is ran right here.

Comment: I understand, however I can't reproduce this from my side without the rest of your code so I can't help, can you please post all necessary code for us to be able to run this on our end?